# Detect if a cookie is a first party cookie

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, cookies

Is there a way to determine if a cookie is first party or not? In PHP or js? I opened up my $_COOKIE variable and can only see the cookie name and value, is there anywhere else I can gather information of who created the cookie/its origin? I'm working within wordpress if that helps my situation.

Comment: the best way is to encrypt your cookies with your own algorithm, if anything isnt encrypted your way, then it's not yours.